# Thread and RandomReal

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, random

I am trying to use `Thread` to apply a function involving `RandomReal` but it does not work as I expected.

If I have the function

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y
```

I can use `Thread` to map over a list of x values of interest

```
Thread[f[{1, 2, 3}, 4]]
```

I cannot, however, do this if I have the function

```
f[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{x , y}]
```

If I call the Thread function again I get the following error
[image: error message]
[image: error message]

I expected to get as output the results of

```
{f[1,4], f[2,4], f[3,4]}
```

so basically 3 random numbers.  Probably more importantly than why this doesn't work - is how can I replicate this behaviour when using `RandomReal` in the function?

Comment: Side note: `f[#, 4]&/@{1,2,3}` is more natural in this case.

Comment: @xzczd I didn't see your comment but we're thinking the same. The mechanism of `Thread` is somewhat a bit of complicated and I rarely use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Thread[Unevaluated@f[{1, 2, 3}, 4]]
```

> ```
> {1.946182809, 2.842898138, 3.571798651}
> ```

### Explanation

[Documentation of `Thread`](https://wolfram.com/xid/0y791e-fpnhwv):

> `Thread` evaluates the whole expression before threading.

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y

Thread[f[{1, 2, 3}, 4]]
=> Thread[{1, 2, 3} + 4] (* Evaluates *)
=> Thread[{5, 6, 7}]
=> {5, 6, 7} (* Threads... trivially *)
```

Since `+` is `Listable`, nothing went wrong even though `f` was evaluated first.

```
f[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{x, y}]

Thread[f[{1, 2, 3}, 4]]
=> Thread[RandomReal[{1, 2, 3}, 4]] (* Evaluates... *)
=> (* Error *)
```

"Evaluate first" passes wrong arguments to `RandomReal`.

```
f[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{x, y}]

Thread[Unevaluated@f[{1, 2, 3}, 4]]
=> Thread[f[{1, 2, 3}, 4]] (* Evaluates *)
=> {f[1,4],f[2,4],f[3,4]} (* Threads *)
=> ...
```

`Unevaluated` helps `f` survive the evaluation.

---

```
f[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{x, y}]
list = {1, 2, 3};

Thread[Unevaluated@f[list, 4]]
=> Thread[f[list, 4]] (* Evaluates *)
=> f[list, 4] (* Threads... Nothing to thread! *)
=> RandomReal[{1, 2, 3}, 4]
=> (* Error *)
```

`list` should not survive the evaluation, while `f` should. We can use `Inactive` on `f` and `Activate` afterwards:

```
f[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{x, y}]
list = {1, 2, 3};

Activate@Thread[Inactive[f][list, 4]]
=> Activate@Thread[Inactive[f][{1, 2, 3}, 4]] (* Evaluates *)
=> Activate@{Inactive[f][1,4], Inactive[f][2,4], Inactive[f][3,4]} (* Threads *)
=> {f[1,4], f[2,4], f[3,4]} (* Activates *)
=> ...
```

Actually, there're many simpler and faster ways to do this, like:

```
f[#, 4] & /@ list
```

Comment: Hope I can get away with a follow-up question.  Why does this fail if you replace the `{1,2,3}` with something like `list = {1,2,3}; Thread[Unevaluated@f[list, 4]]` ?  Is it because of the Unevaluated?

Comment: @Esme_ Yes, in this case the `{1,2,3}` is not explicit. In other words, `Thread` cannot _see_ the `{1,2,3}` inside `list`. A possible solution: `list = {1, 2, 3}; With[{list = list}, Thread[Unevaluated@f[list, 4]]]`, another: `list = {1, 2, 3}; Thread[Unevaluated@f[#, 4]] &@list`.

Comment: @Esme_ Yes, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks SneezeFor16Min and xzczd for the explanations and detailed answers.  Despite many years of using Mathematica I'm still only touching the surface!